# XPath expression to fetch price field in this markup

Tags: html, web-scraping, xpath

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="D(ib) Mend(20px)">
   <fin-streamer class="Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)" data-symbol="TSLA" data-test="qsp-price" data-field="regularMarketPrice" data-trend="none" data-pricehint="2" value="860" active="">860.00</fin-streamer>
   <fin-streamer class="Fw(500) Pstart(8px) Fz(24px)" data-symbol="TSLA" data-test="qsp-price-change" data-field="regularMarketChange" data-trend="txt" data-pricehint="2" value="-44.549988" active=""><span class="C($negativeColor)">-44.55</span></fin-streamer>
   <fin-streamer class="Fw(500) Pstart(8px) Fz(24px)" data-symbol="TSLA" data-field="regularMarketChangePercent" data-trend="txt" data-pricehint="2" data-template="({fmt})" value="-0.049250998" active=""><span class="C($negativeColor)">(-4.93%)</span></fin-streamer>
   <fin-streamer class="D(n)" data-symbol="TSLA" changeev="regularTimeChange" data-field="regularMarketTime" data-trend="none" value="" active="true"></fin-streamer>
   <fin-streamer class="D(n)" data-symbol="TSLA" changeev="marketState" data-field="marketState" data-trend="none" value="" active="true"></fin-streamer>
   <div id="quote-market-notice" class="C($tertiaryColor) D(b) Fz(12px) Fw(n) Mstart(0)--mobpsm Mt(6px)--mobpsm Whs(n)"><span>At close: February 11 04:00PM EST</span></div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get to the price value, which is the first value in the `<fin-streamer>` element tag.

I am able to select the parent div, using this selector:

> ['//div[@class="D(ib) Mend(20px)"]

However, once selected, it is not clear how to select the non standard tag element `<fin-streamer>` and on to the price field.

How do I extract the price field?

Comment: Try this `//*[@data-test="qsp-price"]/text()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this expression

```
//div[@class="D(ib) Mend(20px)"]/fin-streamer[@data-test="qsp-price"]/text()
```

should output

```
860.00
```